# How do I select a specific value from an array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection called Posts which has a field called comments that holds an array of objects. Each comment object has the fields author, content, and likes.

So the model would look something like this:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    user: "DarthVader"
    comments: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            author: "stormtrooper",
            content: "I love the republic",
            likes: 3
        },
         {
            _id: 2,
            author: "stormtrooper2",
            content: "I missed everything",
            likes: 5
        }
    ]
}
// more documents...
```

How will I be able to select a specific comment's like count given that I have the post's _id and comment's _id?

I have tried using the .select, .find, and $elemMatch to no luck.

Like the following:

```
await Post.find({_id: postDataID, "comments": {$elemMatch: {_id: commentDataID}}})

await Post.find({_id: postDataID, "comments._id": {$elemMatch: {_id: commentDataID}}})
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output sample document?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question but, I just want to be able to retrieve the like count of, let's say, a comment with the _id: 1 which in this case would be 3 using the mongoose query.

Comment: So the output document would be `{ likes: 3 }`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$comments"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "comments._id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$comments"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      likes: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p22RKw84hWu)

Input:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    user: "DarthVader",
    comments: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        author: "stormtrooper",
        content: "I love the republic",
        likes: 3
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        author: "stormtrooper2",
        content: "I missed everything",
        likes: 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    user: "Nick",
    comments: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        author: "stormtrooper",
        content: "I love the republic",
        likes: 8
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        author: "stormtrooper2",
        content: "I missed everything",
        likes: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "likes": 3
  }
]
```